# Optimizing Ruby Code for Webscraping Running in AWS Lambda

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, aws-serverless

I am writing a simple serverless app to scrape data about available live sports events. I am using:

- serverless chrome v1.0.0-37 (https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome)
- chromedriver 2.37
- selenium-webdriver gem 3.141.0
- writing code in Ruby 2.5 and running it in AWS lambda.

Here is my code:

```
def find_event_ids
  visit_page
  elements = @driver.find_elements(class: 'event').map do |event_el|
    event_el.attribute('id')
  end
end

def setup_driver
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(binary: ENV['BINARY_PATH'])
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
  options.add_argument('--window-size=1280x1696')
  options.add_argument('--disable-application-cache')
  options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
  options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
  options.add_argument('--log-level=0')
  options.add_argument('--single-process')
  options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
  options.add_argument('--homedir=/tmp')
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, driver_path: ENV['DRIVER_PATH'], options: options
  @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
end

def visit_page
  @driver.navigate.to "https://sports.williamhill.com/betting/en-gb/in-play/football"
end

def call_webdriver_handler(event:, context:)
  setup_driver
  results = find_event_ids
  @driver&.quit
  { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.generate(results) }
end
```

I wanted to expose an API with Amazon API Gateway. The problem is when there are many events, I always receive a timeout when calling this API.

I have already tried:

- Changing chrome webdriver options
- Setting max timeouts in API Gateway
- Rewriting the code to return events paginated, e.g.:

```
  def find_event_ids(page = 1)
    visit_page
    elements = @driver.find_elements(class: 'event')
    paginated_elements_data = elements[(RECORDS_PER_PAGE * (page - 1)), (RECORDS_PER_PAGE * page - 1)].map do |event_el|
      event_el.attribute('id')
    end
    {
      metadata: {
        total_count: elements.count,
        total_pages: (elements.count.to_f / RECORDS_PER_PAGE).ceil,
        current_page: page,
      },
      data: paginated_elements_data
    }
  end
```

It was only slightly faster, so I guess that `@driver.find_elements(class: 'event')` is much more time consuming then `.map`.

Is there any way to optimize my code? My goal would be able to scrape up to 100 sports events. If not, do you recommend any other tool or technology I can use to scrape live sports events with code in AWS Lambda?